# getting error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc"

Tags: c++

This is my first post on Stackoverflow and I hope I will find a solution to my problem.

This is main of the class song, where it gets an metadata ( length, year, genre).
I think the problem is coming from the function enumToString but I'm not sure :/

```
Song::Song(Artist artist, string title)
{
    an_artist = &artist;
    a_title = title;
}


Artist Song::artist() const
{
    return *an_artist;
}

void Song::artist(Artist artist)
{
    an_artist = &artist;
}

string Song::title() const
{
    return a_title;
}

void Song::title(string title)
{
    a_title = title;
}

Metadata *Song::metadata()
{
    return &a_metadata;
}

// converting enum to string
const string enumToString (Genre val)
{
    switch (val)
    {
        case Genre::Funk:
            return "Funk";
        case Genre::Soul:
            return "Soul";
        case Genre::Rap:
            return "Rap";
        case Genre::Rock:
            return "Rock";
        case Genre::Unknown:
            return "Unknown";
        default:
            return "Not recognized!";
    }
}

string Song::info()
{
    int minutes = a_metadata.lengthInSeconds / 60;
    int seconds = a_metadata.lengthInSeconds % 60;


    cout << "( "<< a_title << " ) " << "by " << an_artist->name()
                  << " Genre: " << enumToString(a_metadata.a_genre) << ","
                  << " Length: "<< minutes << ":" << seconds << ","
                  << " Published: " << a_metadata.publishedInYear;
    return "";
}
```

I'm trying to print the songs, but after the first one I get this error, and I don't really       know where the problem is. This is my second time coding with C++ ^^ Thank you in advance

```
Moez of fawez
fawez : Moez, Sofiene, Rostom, Amine, 

( bara hakeka ) by �>��) Genre: Funk, Length: 15:0, Published: 1980
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Comment: Storing pointer to arguments looks a bad idea because the arguments are valid only in the functions and the stored pointers are useless after returning from the functions.

Comment: A good way to fix these kinds of run-time bugs is to use a debugger. Do you know how to use one?

Comment: You should really familiarize yourself with the use of "*" and "&" in c++ to get a better understanding as to when to use them. For example, ```an_artist = &artist``` is setting your member variable to the address associated with the parameter passed in. Most likely why it is printing black diamonds with white questions marks.

Comment: @cigien I'm working on Qt creator, and there is a Debugger but I don't really understand what it is telling me :/

Comment: I would recommend learning how to use that, there should be decent tutorials online if you search for it. That'll be a lot better than asking for debugging help every time you face these issues :)

Comment: @NullPointer I get "field 'an_artist has incomplete type 'Artist' " when I try not to use a pointer

Comment: @cigien I will do that, thanks anyway ^^

Comment: @Mysterion What is an "Artist"?

Comment: @NullPointer a class of a two sub-classes Group and Person.

Comment: Your bug is here `an_artist = &artist;` you can't store the address of a temporary in a pointer and expect it to work later. The temporary no longer exists after the constructor goes out of scope. My advice is to get rid of the pointer and instead store an Artist object.

Comment: @NullPointer https://imgur.com/YF7iFU4 / https://imgur.com/I6wkBH2 / https://imgur.com/zyjS90L maybe this will help you to understand what I mean

Comment: @Mysterion Did you try ```Artist *an_artist = new Artist();``` as the declaration. This will dynamically allocate memory for your artist object. But you also have to make sure you are careful and only call it once, or, delete[] it from memory. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: @NullPointer tried to do that, but I get " invalid use of incomplete type 'class Artist' ". Maybe providing the full code will be more helpful https://github.com/Digiyang/Software-Engineering

Comment: @Mysterion in artist.cpp: ```void Artist::addSong(Song *song)
{
    the_songs.push_back(song);
    song->artist(*this);
}``` specifically the line ```song->artist(*this)``` is passing the objects own address through a pointer. However, in song.cpp: ```void Song::artist(Artist artist)
{
    Artist artistou = artist;
}``` it doesn't expect this.

Comment: @NullPointer thank you very much for the hint, it did solve my problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I am posting the answer here so that one does not have to go through the comments in order to find it.

In the function "addSong" from artist.cpp:

```
void Artist::addSong(Song *song)
{
    the_songs.push_back(song);
    song->artist(*this); // line I will be referencing
}
```

You are passing the object's "this" pointer. Every object has its own "this" pointer which gives access to its own memory address. Learn more here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_this_pointer.htm

However in the function "artist" from song.cpp:

```
void Song::artist(Artist artist)
{
    Artist artistou = artist;
}
```

Side note: Please use setters and getters (Encapsulation) in this scenario. I.e. void set_artist(...) and Artist get_artist().

The parameter does not reflect you passing in a pointer to the memory address of the object. Also, since artistou is declared and defined locally inside of this function, once the program leaves the scope of this function, so will this variables life leave from your computers memory. This variable should be defined in song.h as:

```
Artist *artistou = new Artist();
```

and then deleted[] from memory once no longer used as to avoid memory leaks.

Overall, please review some good coding practices on C++. As you said you are new, I am going to drop some links to some important topics that I feel you could benefit from learning.

Inheritance: https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/inheritance

Encapsulation and Getters and Setters: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_encapsulation.asp

Dynamic Memory Management: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory

I hope this helped!